# Panel's visible property won't change from 'False' to 'True'

Tags: vb.net, panel, visible

I am stumped on this one. I have a `panel` (`pnlKeyPad`) that won't change the `visible` property when I try to set it to `True`. But when I try to set the `Dock` Property to `DockStyle.Fill` it succeeds. I have tried them in different orders, setting the `parent` property to the `splitpanel` and nothing seems to fix it. The `panel` is on a `splitpanel` that is visible. The `panel` is set to `visible = false` by default.

Any ideas of why this panel won't switch to visible when I specifically set it to visible?

Update: I tried changing the default value to `True` and setting it to `False` in the code and when trying to change it back to `True` it worked in the load but not later in other sub routines.

Code:

```
Me.pnlKeyPad.Visible = True    'Doesn't work

Me.pnlKeyPad.Dock = DockStyle.Fill      'Works when checking the value through debugger
savCCAmt = savGrandAmt - savOptionAmt
Me.txtCCAmt.Text = Decimal.Round(savCCAmt, 2).ToString("f2")
Me.txtCCAmt.Focus()
Me.txtCCAmt.Select(0, Me.txtCCAmt.TextLength) 
Me.txtHelp.Text = aryHelp(13)   'Giving weird values
Me.txtHelp.Select(0, Me.txtHelp.TextLength)   'Giving weird values
Me.txtHelp.ForeColor = Color.Blue
```

Comment: What is the initial size of the panel? It seems that the panel remains invisible because of other controls on your form.

Comment: The initial size of the panel is 541,142. I have 14 buttons and a textbox. Its a numeric keypad basically. That is on the panel*

Comment: Could you try to set the size of the panel after setting visible to true?

Comment: I am trying to set the dock property to fill after setting visible to true. But it seems like the rest of my commands in the else statement are being set either.

Comment: Look in the Output window.  Do you see a "first chance exception"?

Comment: @HansPassant I am not seeing anything in the Output window

Comment: Hey, So I appreciate all your help that you both have given! It was a problem due to my own stupidity. I didn't correctly call the sub routine which resulted in not being able to access the properties. Thanks again!